# Show that $H$ is an invariant subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is an exercise from my textbook:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ such that $G=H\cup aH$, for some $a \in G$. Show that $H$ is an invariant subgroup of $G$.

**What I have tried:** I proved that if $a^{-1}Ha=H$, then $H$ is an invariant subgroup of $G$. However how could I prove that $a^{-1}Ha=H$?

Could you help me?

Comment: This result is usually phrased as: every subgroup of index 2 is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Show that either $H=G$, or $H\cap aH=\varnothing$. If $H\cap aH=\varnothing$, show that it must be the case that $aH=Ha$, and then apply your previous result.

Comment: I can only prove that $Ha \subset aH$.

Comment: @Paul: If $H\cup aH=G$ and $H\cap aH=\varnothing$, then $aH=G\setminus H$, and $H$ has exactly two left cosets. But that means that $H$ has exactly two right cosets, and one of them is $H$, so the other must be ... ?

Comment: The number of left cosets always equal to the number of right cosets?

Comment: @Paul Yes. ${}{}{}{}$.

Comment: @Paul: Yes: $|aH|=|H|=|Ha|$ for each $a\in G$, the left (right) cosets of $H$ partition $G$, so the number of left (right) cosets of $H$ must be $\dfrac{|G|}{|H|}$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard trick: Either $H=G$ (in which case the result is obvious), or $aH = G \setminus H$ (this is the set-theoretic difference). In this case, you also have $Ha = G \setminus H$, therefore $aH = Ha$.